# What was the Georgian calendar date when the moon was split?

Tags: history, miracles, moon

I'm reading this:

> People living in other parts of the world witnessed the splitting of
> the moon as well, which happened 18 June 1178, corresponding with
> Dhul-Hijjah 29, 573 on the Islamic calendar.

https://islamicreminder.org/the-splitting-of-the-moon-witnessed-in-other-parts-of-the-world/

I believe this **Dhul-Hijjah 29, 573** is a reference to an Islamic date.

However, I think Islamic calendar is based on the day Prophet emigrated.

So how can it be Islamic year 573 if miracle happened in his lifetime, Am I missing something?

Comment: The link you have given is a blog and not part of Islamic teachings. As such you should ask this question from the author of the blog. Obviously if انشق القمر is interpreted to mean the event mentioned in ahadith then this can not be the same event as that witnessed at Canterbury since there is a difference of several hundred years between them. An alternate tafsir of the verse is that the moon will split in the future near the day of judgement, however even that IMO does not fit well with the alleged Canterbury incident.

Comment: First of all we have an issue the Georgian calendar was invented in the 16th century.... And before the calendars were corrected several times so how can we count back or forth  correctly? An agreement on a correct date definition is needed.

Comment: @UmH question is not about content of the blog but is more about how to convert islamic date to georgian calendar date.